# How to sort imports in alphabeticall order in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to force IntelliJ to order imports alphabetically?
So it should add import in lexicographical order and sort all imports that are not in good order when formatting the code.

Answer (score 23):

Reformatting code optimizes the imports by default, but it is also possible to invoke `Code | Optimize Imports` separately.

You can configure the order of imports in:
`Preferences/Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java`. Select the `Imports` tab and look under the `Import Layout` header at the bottom.

By default, imports are alphabetically ordered, except for the `java.*` and `javax.*` imports.

Comment: For example i get error while checking code style saying: `Wrong lexicographical order for 'lombok.Setter' import. Should be before 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties'`. `lombok.Setter` is not added in `Import Layout` and i do not wan't to add it manually. While trying to format code - order of imports remains the same.

Comment: Anyone wrestling with this who finds there way here:  Look at Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java  == Imports tab, look for Import Layout editor down at the bottom of the page.  Uncheck the import java.* rule.  This is actually not the way I would do it. I would personally go with the default and have the java.* and javax.* by themselves. But CHECKSTYLE doesn't like that.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  Building on what @bas-leijdekkers said that the default sort order is alphabetical, I was able to get my imports in the correct alphabetical order demanded by checkstyle, by doing this:

- go into File > Settings
- Go into Editor > Code Style > Java, Imports tab
- Delete all entries in the "Import Layout" table.  I had several in here by default, and maybe you do too.  Note you cannot delete the "all other imports" entries, but you can reorder them depending upon your checkstyle requirements.
- Click OK.
- Then, use the Optimize Imports action in any offending file.

This worked for me, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In case, none of the above answers work, try updating the `ktlint` version and then running `./gradlew ktlint`. It was only solution for me that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is the order between the java and javax imports, then you can simply move it by clicking the Up and Down button on the `Layout static imports separately` section.

[image: move the import by clicking the up and down button]

For example, if we have this order:

- import java.*
- import javax.*

Then if we do the `Optimize Imports`, it will order the imports like this:

```java
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

Comment: Nope, the question is about all possible imports that you can imagine.